# Filter web part list from URL parameter

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, filter, project-server

I want to have a site template, that has a central web part list on it (I managed to make this, using SharePoint Designer. Added a Data-View) which is filtered by some data from the URL, or from a local list (which has one item, an ID)

So for example :

```
       Central List
ID                       Name            Type     Info1        Info2
3412158-13321-5431       Project 1       -        blabla       blabla
9123158-13321-5431       Project 2       -        blabla       blabla
3691548-13321-5431       Project 3       -        blabla       blabla
6812158-13321-5431       Project 4       -        blabla       blabla
       ............
```

Each site would have a small list, which would look like this :

```
 ProjectID
 3412158-13321-5431 (this would be different for each website)
```

I want to show the central list on every site, but filter it according to the current sites smaller lists value (I did this manually with a **Connection** on the two lists, and on the ID value, but I want to do it programmatically)

Is there a way, to modify the web parts code to add a filtering, that would take a value from the sites URL and filter the list accordingly?